# Creating asp.net application exe

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I created an application for property selling. One of my client need same application for windows. How can I convert same asp.net application to windows application please help me.

Comment: there is no straight forward way to convert `asp.net` web application to `windows` application ..you have to create windows application from scratch also you can use your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magical way to do this but if you are using the .net language for both windows and the website then it could be that you could use the same objects etc and just change the front end / views.

This largely depends on how well the code was written in the first place though.

Comment: So I need to convert my  web application to windows??

Comment: I got one link for creating exe of web application but it is not working in .net 4.0 http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/142022/Creating-exe-for-ASP-net-Web-application